# Is it possible to use a SUM query on INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND datatypes?

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to use a SUM query to give me the results of adding two columns together?
These columns use the INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND datatype and I want to add the time from both columns to give me a total time.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Did you get an error message perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

`SUM` is for *aggregating* multiple rows, adding values together. To add two columns from the same row, you use `+`. For example, given a table `T` with this data:

```
 A | B
---+---
 1 | 2
 3 | 4
```

You can write `SELECT SUM(a), SUM(b) FROM t` to get a single row that uses addition to aggregate the rows of `T`:

```
 SUM(A) | SUM(B)
--------+--------
      4 |      6
```

or `SELECT a + b FROM t` to add the two columns together:

```
 A+B
-----
   3
   7
```

or either `SELECT SUM(a) + SUM(b) FROM t` or `SELECT SUM(a+b) FROM t` (as you prefer) to combine the two effects:

```
 SUM(A)+SUM(B)                 SUM(A+B)
---------------               ----------
            10                       10
```

---

For `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND`, the situation is a bit trickier, because [the `SUM` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions148.htm#sthref1799) only works for "any numeric datatype or any nonnumeric datatype that can be implicitly converted to a numeric datatype". So you have to do some conversions back and forth. Given this table:

```
 A                  | B
---------------------+-------------------
 +1 01:01:01.000001 | +2 02:02:02.000002
 +3 03:03:03.000003 | +4 04:04:04.000004
```

this query:

```
SELECT NUMTODSINTERVAL(SUM(EXTRACT(DAY FROM a + b)), 'DAY') +
       NUMTODSINTERVAL(SUM(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM a + b)), 'HOUR') +
       NUMTODSINTERVAL(SUM(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM a + b)), 'MINUTE') +
       NUMTODSINTERVAL(SUM(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM a + b)), 'SECOND') AS "SUM(A+B)"
  FROM t
;
```

will give this result:

```
 SUM(A+B)
---------------------
 +10 10:10:10.000010
```

Comment: Does this work with the INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND datatype though?

Comment: @Max: The `+` part does, but the `SUM` part doesn't. I've updated my answer to address that.

Answer (score 1):

you can add intervals, no problem:

```
SQL> select a, b, a+b from t;

A                    B                    A+B
-------------------- -------------------- -----------------------------
+01 00:00:00.000000  +00 00:05:00.000000  +000000001 00:05:00.000000000
+02 00:00:00.000000  +00 00:50:00.000000  +000000002 00:50:00.000000000
+02 00:14:24.000000  +00 00:50:12.000000  +000000002 01:04:36.000000000
```

Comment: You can `+` them, but you can't `SUM` them.

Comment: @ruakh correct, but the OP asked to add two columns together, and not perform a set operation.

Comment: The OP specified `SUM`. If you think that's wrong, then you should explain why it's wrong . . . except that you needn't bother, because my answer had already explained that stuff. ;-)